# MySQL join over three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: Products, Requests, Bookings.

```
Table Products (with all product categories):
name, ..
A1, ..
A1, ..
A2, ..
A2, ..
A2, ..
A3, ..
B1, ..
..

Table Requests (with a state for every request):
name, failed 
A1, 0
A2, 1
A3, 0
A2, 0
..

Table Bookings:
name, ..
A1, ..
A2, ..
..
```

What I need is a joined output with summary data like this:

```
prod_category, count_requests, count_failed, count_bookings
A1, 1, 0, 1
A2, 2, 1, 1
A3, 6, 0, null
B1, null, null, null
```

I've already three separate queries - they works good but I can't get it to work with only one query.

Here is an example of one of my sql queries:

```
SELECT
    T2.n AS category_name, T1.c AS count_requests
FROM
    (SELECT
       object_name as n,
       count(object_name) as c
    FROM
       requests
    GROUP BY n) T1
    RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT distinct
       object_name as n
    FROM
       products) T2 ON T1.n = T2.n
ORDER BY T2.n ASC;
```

Query's output:

```
# category_name, count_requests
'A1', '8'
'A2', '3'
'C1', NULL
'E1', '9'
'E2', '16'
'E3', '3'
'F1', '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all requests that doesn't fail also result in a row in bookings there is no need to join in bookings at all.

```
select p.name, 
      count(r.name) as count_requests, 
      sum(r.failed) as count_failed,
      count(r.name) - sum(r.failed) as count_bookings
  from products p
  left join requests r on (p.name = r.name)
 group by p.name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da461/6

Comment: Hmmmm nice thinking... +1

Comment: Hi, Andreas, that is what i'm lookin for, thank you.

But now I've the problem, that in my described example all tables have the column named "name", but in effect they have different namens (i.e. products.name, requests.object_name). Only their content is the category in different spelling. Do you know how to adapt you solution for that?

Comment: Sure, you can use _on_ instead of _using_, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  Name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM Requests WHERE name = Products.Name) AS count_requests,
  (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM Requests WHERE name = Products.Name AND failed = 1) AS count_failed,
  (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM Requests WHERE name = Products.Name AND failed = 0) AS count_bookings
FROM Products
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: while technically this would give the correct result it would also be impossible to run on a table with a lot of products/requests as it causes three sub queries for each row, quickly making this a monster to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine, but it is not tested....

```
 SELECT products.name, COUNT(requests.name) AS count_requests, SUM(requests.failed) AS 
 fails, COUNT(bookings.name) AS bookings FROM products LEFT JOIN requests ON 
 products.name=requests.name LEFT JOIN bookings ON products.name=bookings.name 
 GROUP BY products.name ORDER BY products.name
```